# Which compilers provide guarantees (warranties) on generated asm code?

Tags: consistency, software-quality

Please note that the question is about compilers in general, not targeting any particular programming language.

Context: As we know, compilers like gcc and Clang (LLVM) do not provide any guarantees (warranties) on generated asm code by explicitly specifying it:

gcc:

> There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Clang (LLVM):

> There’s no warranty on LLVM at all.

Question: What are the known examples of (mostly commercial I guess) compilers out there that *do* provide guarantees (warranties) on generated asm code? Which guarantees exactly they do they provide? Guarantees of which type exactly?

Example 1. Provide a guarantee that a certain HW instructions will be *always* generated for a places (it source code) where the corresponding operations (for instance, floating-point, operations) are used. I.e. these operations will *never* be optimized in a such way that the dedicated HW instructions will be replaced by some other HW instructions (or combinations of them).

Example 2. Options and their combinations. Provide a guarantee that *any* possible combination of options will *always* lead to desired cumulative effect of these options. I.e. *none* of the supplied option(s) will be silently skipped without generation of a diagnostic message.

UPD1. The `guarantee` means here the ability to always provide advertised (claimed) functionality. I.e. without any hidden effects, silent behaviors (without generation of any diagnostic message), replacing one HW instructions by other HW instructions (so, you cannot say in advance, which exactly HW instructions will be in the generated asm code), etc. -- you get the idea.

> If it doesn't do X they promise to try to fix it?

At least.

> A mathematical proof of correctness?

Preferably. However, to my knowledge the price of mathematically proven software development tools goes high. Do you confirm? And only a specific software projects required to use mathematically proven software development tools.

Comment: What does "guarantee" mean here?  It does X or you get your money back?  If it doesn't do X they promise to try to fix it?  A mathematical proof of correctness? Or what?  Much of this is more about how much you're willing to pay for such a warranty / service contract / etc.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that the motivations behind these statements are legal, not mathematical.  By expressly declining fitness, they not only protect themselves from lawsuits from users, but also for any consequences from the generated code.  Imagine compilers being sued because a reactor blew up.  What company is going to want to face that kind of exposure?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Does it mean that none of the (commercial) compilers claim fitness because of the scenario above?

Comment: IANAL.  That said, the goal of legalese is to protect the company.  If I were writing their EULA, I'd be (way) more worried about the possibilities of the (potentially HUGE) damages we'd be subject to by making guarantees than the (vague) possibilities of more sales such a promise might prompt.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Interesting, thanks! Then what are the main advantages of commercial compilers over non-commercial (open source) compilers? Support 24/7? Quick bug fixes (if any)? Support of specific target architectures? I've thought that commercial compilers provide to the end user more confidence w.r.t. correctness of generated code.